# My PersistentVolumeClaim won't bind to NFS PersistentVolume -- what am I doing wrong?

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes

My PersistentVolume is configured like so:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv0001
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  nfs:
    path: /volume2/K8s_NFS
    server: 172.16.66.50
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Recycle
```

My PVC is configured thusly:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: nfs-claim1
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
```

This seems to match to me, however the result is that it does not bind:

```
Name:          nfs-claim1
Namespace:     default
StorageClass:
Status:        Pending
Volume:
Labels:        <none>
Annotations:   <none>
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:
Access Modes:
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Used By:       <none>
Events:
  Type    Reason         Age                   From                         Message
  ----    ------         ----                  ----                         -------
  Normal  FailedBinding  86s (x26 over 7m33s)  persistentvolume-controller  no persistent volumes available for this claim and no storage class is set
```

I have confirmed that all three nodes in my cluster can mount the volume.  What am I missing?

Comment: As `Alif Biswas's` answer should resolve your issue, I will only add additional information. You can miss providing specific `storageclass` if you already have definied `default storageclass`, details [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#the-storageclass-resource). Also please keep in mind that with [AccessMode](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#the-storageclass-resource) `RWO`, you are able only to mount this volume on one node. If you want to mount on different nodes, you should use `RWX` access mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define storageClassName in specs which will be used to bind PersistentVolumeClaim requests to PersistentVolume.

Updated config, Persistent Volume:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv0001
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  claimRef:
    name: nfs-claim1
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  nfs:
    path: /volume2/K8s_NFS
    server: 172.16.66.50
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Recycle
```

Persistent Volume Claim:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: nfs-claim1
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
```

[details](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/#create-a-persistentvolume)